# Can't Delete Ghost Folder

Tags: windows

In my desktop has one system folder, it is no name and no properties, I can not delete and rename it, even I use windows safe mode. Only when I use different name to login windows, it is disappeared.

This ghost Icon no name and no property. After right click on the folder, Only show three items "Cut", "Create Shortcut" and "Delete" in the box, not like normal will show lot of items in box. If click any one of three item, can not cut or delete this icon.

Desktop like this: [image]

After right click on the ghost icon: [image]

Comment: This ghost Icon no name and no property. After right click on the folder, Only show three items "Cut", "Create Shortcut" and "Delete" in the box, not like normal will show lot of items in box. If click any one of three item, can not cut or delete this icon.

Comment: run CheckDisk on the drive... from the cmd prompt ( change c: to the correct partition if not c: ) ">chkdsk c: /r"

Comment: A screenshot of the folder might help at the very least te full path is required to understand the problem.

Comment: Can you open the folder? If so, what are the contents. Note that it is a "system folder", meaning that there may not necessarily be a physical file backing it. This could be the result of a program not being uninstalled cleanly.

Comment: No, I can't open this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I thought it may be a system folder, too. But the folder is in your `desktop` as seen on your screenshots. Generally normal applications do not store their system folders on the desktop. So most probably its because of a spyware or a virus. So you should clean your pc with an antivirus software. You may also setup a free version of Spybot (www.safer-networking.org) for searching spywares.